# Baby Rudin, Chapter 11, Problem 1

Tags: measure-theory

I couldn't find it here, so apologies for a possible duplicate in advance.

The problem is sated as follows:

If $f \geq 0$ and $\int_E f\,d\mu=0$, prove that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere on E. $\textit{Hint:}$ Let $A_n$ be the subset of $E$ on which $f(x)>\frac{1}{n}$. Take $A=\cup_{n} A_n$.Then $\mu (A)=0$ if and only if $\mu (A_n)=0$ for every $n$.

My troubles arise at the proof of the statement in the hint. So if we have a set $A$ with $\mu(A)=0$ and it is represented as $\cup A_n$ then $\sum \mu(A_n)=0$ and thus $\mu(A_n)=0$, right? But if we know that $\mu(A_n)=0$ and $A=\cup A_n$ wouldn't it immediately follow that $\mu(A)=0$ as a countable sum of zeros?

The solution in the manual implies that it's not so.

Please help me understand the solution to the problem, thank you.

Comment: Should be "… if and only if $\mu(A_n) = 0$ _for all_ $n$".

Comment: yes, you're right, thank you

Comment: I've no idea what the solution manual does, but it is pretty easy. If $\mu(A) = 0$, then $A_n \subset A$ implies $\mu(A_n) = 0$ for all $n$. And if $\mu(A_n) = 0$ for all $n$, then $\mu(A) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) = 0$, since $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $\bigcup A_n = A$.

Comment: You could also use $$\mu(A) \leqslant \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(A_n).$$ If $\mu(A_n) = 0$ for all $n$, we have equality in that, but since the $A_n$ are generally not disjoint, the inequality can be strict. If some $A_n$ has positive measure, the right hand side is $+\infty$, and the left hand side can be finite.